# How to get all values of first row of excel - vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get all values (not empty) of first row of excel .

```
oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).End(xlDown).column
```

but I think this is wrong.
I want to loop it and show value inside a MsgBox.

Comment: Why are you using `.End` or `.Column`?

Comment: This piece of code is for testing.

Comment: Ok, but `.End(xlDown)` doesn't belong at all if you're only looking at the first row.

Comment: To reference the 'populated' cells in row 1, starting with cell `A1`, you could use `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1"): Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`. Then you can loop over the cells of this range to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loop Through the Cells of the Header Row

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim hrg As Range
Set hrg = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

Dim hCell As Range

For Each hCell In hrg.Cells
    MsgBox hCell.Address(0, 0) & " = " & hCell.Value
Next hCell
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your wording, you need "all values (not empty) of first row of excel" sheet.
you can then use:

- `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` function to count the number of not empty
  cell in a range
- `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to select not empty cells

as follows:

```
With oBook ' reference your workbook
    With .Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference "Sheet1" worksheet of referenced workbook
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) ' reference row 1 range from column 1 rightwards to last not empty cell in referenced worksheet
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then ' if at least one not empty cell
                Dim cel As Range
                    For Each cel In .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop thorugh referenced range not empty cells

                        Debug.Print cel.Value

                    Next
            End If
        End With
    End With
End With
```